# python - how to capture errors from a ghostscript command run in a subprocess

Tags: python, ghostscript, subprocess

I am running ghostscript in a subprocess, which is working well except I don't seem to be able to capture errors.

```
import subprocess

cmd = 'gs -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile=img-%d.jpeg -r150 -g600x600 sample.pdf'
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), shell=False, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

stderr = p.communicate()

print stderr
```

My problem is whether the command executes correctly or no the stderr always equals:

(None, '')

I made a second attempt specifying both stdout and stderr

```
p = subprocess.Popen(slide_cmd.split(), shell=False, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```

p.stdout gives output but p.stderr still returns on None

Comment: Are you sure there is any output to stderr ? The `None` is normal, you don't have `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, but what about stderr ?

Comment: I have updated my question to include stdout as well as stderr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ghostscript seems to write mostly to STDOUT, except for the summary of fatal errors like

```
GPL Ghostscript 8.71: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

which ends up on STDERR. So, read STDOUT as well and you should be able to capture everything.

In order to help debug this, print the command you're executing in python using subprocess and then use IO redirection in your shell to redirect output to files in order to see on that stream GS outputs what. For example: `gs [args] 2>stderr.txt 1>stdout.txt`

On a side note, you should use `shlex.split()` instead of `str.split()` to tokenize argument lists, see this [note in the subprocess docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).

On a second site note: Once you start substituting 'sample.pdf' with an actual filename using string formatting (`cmd % filename`), make sure you escape that `%d` (because it's meant to be interpreted by GS, not Python) by using `%%d` instead.

Comment: btw thanks for the shlex.split() info. Its always nice when someone provides extra value you did not expect

Comment: @Finglish You're welcome. Edited my question and added one more pointer ;)